# The command `foreman start` is giving a Exec format error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreman

I'm trying to make a new project with Ruby on Rails and I'm installing all the required gems. Everything looks right but when I run `foreman start` I get a list of errors
[image]

I tried reinstalling the gems and updating them but I always get this.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please, post error messages as text, not as photographs of text. This is a programming website, not a [photography.se] website. We want to read&copy&paste&understand the error message, not critique its use of color and perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, webpack cannot be found.
Try to run:

- `npm install` or `yarn install`
- `bundle install`
- `bundle exec rake webpacker:install`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I tried that but it shows the same error. I'm starting to think that my system itself is faulty (other packages are giving me a related error)